# how to render a same component one or multiple time using event handler

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I want to build form in Which there are some text fields as shown in picture

[image: Form]

in this form there is a button and after clicking the **Add Units** button a new form will appear
[image]

how can i render this sub form by using button **onClick Event-Handler** and i also want to render it as many times as i click the button , if i click button one time then it shows the the sub form only one time if i click the button two times then it will show two times

-The main issue is I want the sub form to appear as many time i click the button

(**optional** if i want to  remove the rendered sub form using a button click then please mention the code )

use of react hooks is preferable
you can ask me anything related to question

Comment: Store an array of "units" in a React.useState hook. Every time the add units button is clicked, push some object to the array. Then map over that array, returning the form component for each item in the array.

Comment: sorry did not get it, can you code it?

Comment: const [units, setUnits] = React.useState([]);
<button onClick={() => setUnits(current => [...current, {values: {chasisNo: ""}}])}>Add Units</button> ... {units.map(unit => <YourUnitComponent {...unit} />)}

Comment: If that still doesn't make sense, let me know and I can write it in the answer block. But SO isn't a "code for me" website, so please post what code you've written so far and then people can help based on that.

Comment: no brother it does not work properly . I will give you the code but i just saw your skills and you are not react developer sorry. the problem i am getting now is, when i click the button first time it will render the component two times and when i click the button second time then it will render the component four times. if you think you can solve it then it is good. Btw appreciate your help thanks

Comment: I've been a professional React developer for two years actually. But good luck.

Comment: sorry, I doubted your skills because of your tags mentioned in your profile, here is the code which is not working https://codesandbox.io/s/cocky-haze-dfuq9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example of how to solve your problem. You don't need useEffect, and you don't need three separate state variables. You just need one array of objects.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import ContainerSlot from "./ContainerSlot";

function ReceiptContainer() {
  const [containers, setContainers] = useState([]);

  const handleAddContainer = () => {
    // adding an empty object; you will likely need to
    // initialize this object with whatever values are stored
    // in the container form
    setContainers((current) => [...current, {}]);
  };
  const handleRemove = (index) => {
    const current = [...containers];
    current.splice(index, 1);
    setContainers(current);
  };

  return (
    <div className="receiptContainer container">
      {/* Heading */}
      <div className="receiptContainer__heading mt-3">
        <h4>Container Invoice</h4>
        <hr />
      </div>
      <button onClick={handleAddContainer}>Add container</button>
      <div className="receiptContainer__container">
        {/* You will likely need to pass whatever values are in 
        the container to your ContainerSlot component */}
        {containers.map((container, index) => {
          const handleRemoveClick = () => {
            handleRemove(index);
          };
          return (
            <div
              key={`container-${index}`}
              style={{ display: "flex", alignItems: "center" }}
            >
              <div>
                <ContainerSlot {...container} />
              </div>
              <div>
                <button onClick={handleRemoveClick}>Remove</button>
              </div>
            </div>
          );
        })}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default ReceiptContainer;
```

**EDIT: updated to show how to remove an item**

Comment: Thanks brother, this code run smoothly appreciate your work. I have two queries. 1- Why spread operator is used in <ContainerSlot />. 2- The same way you add component can you delete it by using another button?

Comment: I used the spread operator just for an example of how you might pass the properties of that object to your ContainerSlot component. I assume that object would store some values, and you would need to manipulate those values with ContainerSlot. You can handle that in several different ways, I just listed it for example. And I updated my answer to show how you could remove an item from the array.